# Cant install Vpn and app user certificate

Tags: certificate, vpn, android-11

I can't install a certificate for "Vpn & App user certificate" on Android 11. I tried setting it up via "Settings" menu > "Install from device storage," > "VPN and app user certificate", but I see an error like: "this file can't be used as a VPN & app user certificate".

But weird, two month ago it worked fine, maybe I'm doing something wrong with it?

Comment: Same on android 12. Is it the wrong format?

Comment: Did you find a solution to it?

Comment: @ReyRey well, I haven't another chance and I bought phone with android 7 - it's enough for me and my experiments. Another case was like to change some rows in source code, but I don't want to spoil my android 11

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure you want to install it for "VPN & App User"? In particular, I was trying to install the certificate from Burp proxy and was misled by the [instructions](https://portswigger.net/support/installing-burp-suites-ca-certificate-in-an-android-device) that said

> In some versions of Android, your device will ask if you want to use the certificate for "VPN and apps" or "WiFi".In the "Credential use:" options, you should select "VPN and apps".

In my case with Android 12, there was a 3rd option, "CA certificate". But I tried a few times with "VPN & app user certificate" and it failed, with the same error message you saw. Then I tried "CA certificate", and it worked.

To be fair, the title of the instructions was "Installing Burp's CA Certificate in an Android Device", which gives a clue that it should be CA Certificate, even though it says to select "VPN and apps".

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes, I tried others variants: the installing like CA or for WiFi and it completed successfully, but.. the connection for any app don't work on device and I haven't another idea