# ProxyMan Install CA certificates in Settings for Android Devices

Tags: android, certificate, proxyman

To intercept the api and modify the api response locally, I was setting up ProxyMan to my android device `Pixel-4a` and faced this popup **Install CA certificates in Settings** after I tried to hit `http://proxy.man/ssl` to install the CA certificate from ProxyMan to my device I face the error popup as attached, earlier in my older device it worked fine however for my new device I'm facing this issue, when I click `CLOSE` on the popup window, a toast message appears : `Failed to install certificate`.

I'm facing the issue in Pixel 4a, however the same works fine in Moto X-Play, attached is the screenshot of the popup.

Similar question I found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68917995/4961126), however this doesn't helped me, or I was not able to understand the exact issue, since I'm facing this specifically with ProxyMan and the question asked is for VPN.

[image]

If anyone using proxyMan for intercepting the api on real android device and faced the same issue please help, I'm blocked on this issue and can't move anywhere in my android device, my precise question is:

**Is there any option to reach to the settings where the device certificates are present and how can I add the proxyMan certificate with those certificate?**

Comment: Possible duplicate question
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461360/how-to-install-trusted-ca-certificate-on-android-device)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution [here](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/2844832?hl=en),

Once I hit the api `http://proxy.man/ssl`, the certificate were downloaded in my download package however it was not installed automatically since from Android 11 certificate can not be install automatically and user have to install it manually by following steps:

**Install a certificate**

1. Open your phone's Settings app.
2. Tap Security And then Advanced settings and then Encryption & credentials.
3. Tap Install a certificate And then CA certificate.
4. In the top left, tap Menu .
5. Tap where you saved the certificate.[in my case it was `downloads`]
6. Tap the file.

   - If needed, enter the key store password. Tap OK.
7. Enter a name for the certificate.
   Tap OK.